# How to use LazyColumn in ExposedDropdownMenu?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I found that when there is a lot of data, ExposedDropdownMenuBox will have performance problems.

So I did some searching and found this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/242398344), it says that `LazyColumn` can be used to improve performance.

But I am getting the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Asking for intrinsic measurements of SubcomposeLayout layouts is not supported. This includes components that are built on top of SubcomposeLayout, such as lazy lists, BoxWithConstraints, TabRow, etc. To mitigate this:
>
> if intrinsic measurements are used to achieve 'match parent' sizing,, consider replacing the parent of the component with a custom layout which controls the order in which children are measured, making intrinsic measurement not needed adding a size modifier to the component, in order to fast return the queried intrinsic measurement.

Here is the complete code:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun SageExposedDropdownMenuBox(options: List<DropDownMenuOption>) {

  var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
  
  var selected by remember { mutableStateOf<DropDownMenuOption?>(null) }

  ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
    expanded = expanded,
    onExpandedChange = {
      expanded = !expanded
    }
  ) {

    TextField(
      value = selected?.label ?: "",
      onValueChange = {

      },
      readOnly = true,     
      modifier = Modifier.menuAnchor()
    )

    ExposedDropdownMenu(
      expanded = expanded,
      onDismissRequest = { expanded = false }
    ) {
      LazyColumn {
        items(options) { option ->
          DropdownMenuItem(
            text = { Text(text = option.label) },
            onClick = {
              selected = option
              expanded = false
            }
          )
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I just started to learn jetpack compose, I don't know what `intrinsic measurements` and `ExposedDropdownMenuBox` internal structure.

please tell me how to fix this error.

Answer (score 1):

Until this is properly supported, consider the following workaround: Hard code the lazy column's height based on the single item's height and the maximum height that popup can take. Similarly, adjust the width according to your use case.

```
    val sizeOfOneItem by remember {
        mutableStateOf(50.dp) //assuming height of one menu item 50dp
    }
    val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
    val screenHeight50 by remember {
        val screenHeight = configuration.screenHeightDp.dp
        mutableStateOf(screenHeight / 2) //assuming the drop down menu anchor is in middle of the screen. This is the maximum height that popup menu can take.
    }
    val height by remember(options.size) {
        val itemsSize = sizeOfOneItem * options.size
        mutableStateOf(minOf(itemsSize, screenHeight50))
    }
    ExposedDropdownMenu(
        expanded = expanded,
        onDismissRequest = {
            expanded = false
        }
    ) {
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(500.dp)
                .height(height)
        ) {
            items(options) { option ->
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    onClick = {},
                    text = {
                        Text(text = option.label)
                    }
                )
            }
        }
```